# Export R Leaflet Map to JPEG/SVG/PNG

Tags: r, svg, leaflet, png, jpeg

I would like to export Leaflet maps in HD, with the final product being a map printed A1 size. Is there anyway to do this?

I think exporting it to SVG would be the safest way to ensure that the map is clear on A1.

Comment: You could use rmd to either create a pdf or html as intermediate step?

Comment: Can't you make a static version of the map in ggplot? You could then export to svg

Comment: @Christoph How would you convert the html to svg?

Comment: @Chris, I sorta did everything with leaflet before realising that it cant export to svg

Comment: function `mapshot` in the package `mapview` does the trick..